# Register `product_cat` taxonomy for default post post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Is it possible to register WooCommerc's `product_cat` taxonomy for use by posts?

I have tried the following with no success.

```
function custom_cross_content_type_taxonomies(){
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'product_cat', 'post' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_cross_content_type_taxonomies', 0);
```

I will be writing posts about each of the product categories and it would be nice to group with the same terms without duplicating the taxonomy.

Appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Guys, this not woocommerce specific, the downvote is unnecessary, so are the close vote. This is ageneral issue that fits the scope of this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with woocommerce, but in general, taxonomies are registered via the init hook with a priority of `1` or default priority which is `10`

Your code is fine, so I suspect that your priority is wrong here. In short, you are trying to add the taxonomy to the post type before the taxonomy even exists. Try adding a priority of `11` or higher. This would ensure that the taxonomy is registered before you try to assign it to a specific post type

Comment: The default priority of 10 worked fine for me. It's only because a priority of 0 is being called that it doesn't work, so you can just remove the priority altogether.